# Does IRC support internationalized room names?

Tags: unicode, internationalization, chat, irc

Does IRC support internationalized (UTF-8) room names?

How? A pointer to documentation or a spec would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to RFCs [1459](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1459.html) and [2812](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2812.html), channel names can be made up of any bytes other than \x00 (NUL), \x07 (BELL), \x0A (LF), \x0D (CR), \x20 (space), `,` and `:`.  How those bytes are interpreted is entirely up to the client.  IRC doesn't impose any specific restrictions on the encoding.

> No specific character set is specified. The protocol is based on a set of codes which are composed of eight (8) bits, making up an octet. Each message may be composed of any number of these octets; however, some octet values are used for control codes, which act as message delimiters.

Comment: This is true, but conventions apply on many servers (for example, on Japanese servers the convention is often to interpret channel names and topics in JIS).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use IRCX protocol extensions from Microsoft

Basically you add a '%' character append your UTF-8 string and perform a post-processing on the result replacing characters using this table:

```
\b            " " (blank)          
\c            ","
\\            "\"          
\r            CR          
\n            LF
\t            TAB
```

Here is the link to the specification:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pfenning-irc-extensions-04#page-5

Comment: The essential parts were included for sure, the link is included for reference and is the document explaining the protocol. If you are going to criticize something at least take some time to read the actual text. Looks like you are running a robot here at stackoverflow to earn points or something.

Comment: Well i think this was by mistake, and i got warned by the moderators too!  My sincere appologies for the same! I do carefully these days! Thanks for the commernt

Comment: Ok don't worry, we all make mistakes. Regards.